# Remove '@class' in XStream for Java primitive types

Tags: java, serialization, restlet, xstream

I have this field in a POJO that is serialized into JSON:

```
@XStreamAlias("tags")
List<String> tags;
```

My problem is that the output looks like this:

```
"tags": [
      {
        "@class": "linked-list",
        "string": [
          "test",
          "test2"
        ]
      }
    ],
```

In what way that the output would look like this:

```
"tags": [
          "test",
          "test2"
        ],
```

Just like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add `@XStreamImplicit` annotation:

```
@XStreamImplicit(itemFieldName="tags")
List<String> tags;
```